# Discord bot only works on phone, why?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hey guys I wrote this code for a discord bot,
but it only works when pinging from the mobile app, any idea why thats happening?

```py
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands

client=discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  if message.content.startswith (f'good hbu {client.user.mention}'):
    await message.channel.send('You mentioned me!')

client.run(os.getenv('token'))
```

Comment: Can you give me a server invite so I can try it out?

Comment: sure here u go 
https://discord.gg/vubA2kE6
@ToniSredanović

Answer (score 0):

instead of using client.user.mention, use <@!{client.user.id}> instead so it will work on computers, but not on mobile

your command should look like this

```
if message.content.startswith(f'good hbu <@!{client.user.id}>'):
    await message.channel.send('You mentioned me!')
```

if you want the bot to be usable both, use "or" and add both codes

your command should look like this instead

```
if message.content.startswith(f'good hbu <@!{client.user.id}>') or message.content.startswith(f'good hbu {client.user.mention}'):
    await message.channel.send('You mentioned me!')
```

Comment: Could you provide context (like share the doc) to explain why this happen ?

Comment: so discord on computer is like a web server, but discord on mobile is an application this is why they have different codes on ping checking.

Answer (score 0):

try this at the client definition:

```
client=commands.Bot(command_prefix="prefix here")
```

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#getting-started